# Created an extra mounted drive for Ubuntu 19. I used this drive for around a month and now can't add a new Folder

Tags: mount

I was using this newly mounted drive to store a large Neo4j database, which I've used and created folders in for around a month. Now, even though there's still 90GB space left, I can't add a new folder inside this drive. Drive: /media/User/New Volume.

Tried to update the permissions using: sudo chmod 755 /media, but the permissions are not being updated.

Comment: which filesystem?

Comment: Using: findmnt /dev/nvme0n1p4, FSType = fuseblk. Strangely, it looks like the path changed from /media/user/New Volume to /media/User/New Volume1, though this New Volume1 is not visible in the media folder

Comment: Ubuntu 19?   There is no Ubuntu 19; as standard desktop/server releases use a *yy.mm* format, though *yy* is used for specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances, but they only come out on even years.  I would check you have inodes available, esp. if you've created tons of tiny files on the file-system..

Comment: This new drive very likely is an ` ntfs` formatted drive. Check and repair the file system under Windows and fully disconnect the drive. The healthy ntfs volume will now mount correctly with write permissions.

Comment: remove any external drive (harddrive/DVD/a.s.o) search for data in /media/$USER `sudo rm -rf /media/$USER` the folder will be createt anew, when you put any external disk/stick/DVD in, with  the right permissions (acl).

Comment: @Vanadium, you were right. Somehow this drive got reformatted as NTFS. Had to delete and install a new partition as i did not manage to fix this issue.